# jQuery slideshow loading 1 out of 3 times in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, slideshow

I have a [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) slideshow on my [website](http://www.holzwurm-namibia.com/gallery.php?c=k&g=adler). This image slideshow loads fine on Chrome.

On IE9 this slideshow works fine, but only if it shows up. And that is the problem. It only shows up sometimes. I would say it about 1 out of 3 times. (The same happens when compatibility mode is on)

How can I start searching for this bug? Or rather what is this bug?

**Edit:** I have now noticed that the slideshow actually shows up for a split second but then disappears.

**Edit2:** After removing `data-cycle-loader="wait"` the page seems to loads fine in IE. I cannot explain why though.

Comment: It never loads for me in IE9, fine in FF15 though. Guess this doesn't help much...

Comment: @Timm Actually nice to know that it works in FF. Thank you for that! :-)

Comment: maybe try specify height for .cycle-slideshow height:450px

Comment: It works fine locally, so it must be an issue with loading images and timing, maybe container height isn't set properly the reason could be that plugin is initalized before all images finished loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `data-cycle-loader="wait"` from the slideshow will fix this bug.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is check for any console errors. Press F12 then navigate to the console tab and refresh the page. You should see console errors relating to your code/cycle2 if anything is wrong. Another thing is to check whether or not it works in IE7/8. You can toggle these modes by changing the 'Browser Mode' above the console tab.

The only other thing I could think of is that there is some weird z-indexing issue that is causing the scripts to be hidden behind another element.. or something.

Comment: Thannks. I just did all of these suggestions. There are no (relating) errors in the console, and the problem is the same for all IE modes. I'll have to look at z-indexing next i guess.

Comment: You should also remember to set the z-index on elements that are siblings. So if one element you are trying to z-index above/below another element you have to look up the dom until both have the same parent, then apply the z-indexing to the parent and both children (who are siblings).